# How to pass React props into a p5.js sketch

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I've been working on a project that integrates React with p5.js. I'm having trouble passing my props into the sketch. When I reference my props inside the sketch, I get an error that the props variable is undefined. Does anyone know how to access props in a p5.js sketch?

```
import React from "react";
import p5 from 'p5';

class Sketch extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
    }

    Sketch = (p) => {

        p.setup = () => {
            p.createCanvas(400, 400);
            // Want to reference my props here

        }

        p.draw = () => {
            p.background(0);
            // Or reference props here
           // I get an error if I try something like: p.print(props.name);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.myP5 = new p5(this.Sketch, this.myRef.current);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.myRef}></div>
        )
    }
}

export default Sketch;
```

Comment: Because i am unsure what p5 is - i will write a comment instead. If you want to try to access the props with your class component then you should call `this.props`.

Comment: @Delice I find using `this.props` works outside of the sketch (and then it can be passed into the sketch), but if the prop value changes, then that change won't be reflected in the sketch.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [react-p5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5). Here's a simple example:

```js
// // In a project consisting of multiple modules compiled with webpack
// // or browserify would use import statements:
// import React from 'react';
// import Sketch from 'react-p5';
// // But because we're including dependencies with script tags we just do this
const Sketch = reactP5; 

function Example(props) {
  let x = 50;
  let y = 50;
  
  const setup = (p, canvasParentRef) => {
    // use parent to render the canvas in this ref
    // (without that p5 will render the canvas outside of your component)
    p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight).parent(canvasParentRef);
  };

  const draw = (p) => {
    p.background(0);
    p.fill(props.color || 'blue');
    p.ellipse(x % p.width, y, 70, 70);
    // NOTE: Do not use setState in the draw function or in functions that are executed
    // in the draw function...
    // please use normal variables or class properties for these purposes
    x++;
  };

  return <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Example color="green" />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
  <!-- react-p5 bundles p5.js v1.1.9 and sets window.p5 -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-p5@1.3.19/build/index.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm mainly hoping to integrate p5.js and React with just the p5 library, but I was able to pull some pieces from your code to get it working :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I found that assigning the props to myp5 in the componentDidMount function solved it, like shown below:

```
import React from 'react';
import p5 from 'p5';

class Sketch extends React.Component {

  Sketch(p) {
    p.setup = function() {
      p.createCanvas(400, 400);
      p.print(this.name);
    }

    p.draw = function() {
      p.background(0);
      p.print(this.name);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myP5 = new p5(this.Sketch, this.myRef.current);
    myp5.name = this.props.name;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.myRef}></div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sketch;
```